# Jquery Mobile - Can I trigger javascript without rel=external?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building mobile web sites with Jquery Mobile. I also have a javascript-based tracking system that I want to implement, much like Google Analytics. But with Jquery Mobile, the caching is so solid that unless I put rel=external on every link, the page it links to doesn't execute the javascript on the page and thus, no tracking. I want to take advantage of the mobile caching because of performance issues, but I also need to track the pages. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Example: http://wec.gfx.com (on mobile)

The first page is a splash page and without adding rel=external to the link, the menu page (page 2) doesn't get tracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your JS in the `pagebeforeshow` event for each page.